# dijit.form.Select broken in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, dojo, spring-webflow

Thanks Microsoft, thanks a lot.

We're using dojo/dijit controls included in the Spring Webflow releases. Currently we are a ResourceServlet;

```
org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet
```

to access the dojo/dijit libraries contained within

```
org.springframework.js-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Unfortunately IE9 has broken all our dijit.form.Select controls, they no longer drop down with the information that's suppose to be inside them. They work fine on every single other browser known to man, but not Microsoft's latest lump.

I believe the version of Dojo contained in the Webflow release mentioned above is 1.4.3. However I've read that Dojo 1.6.1 and possibly 1.5.1 are being updated to fix many of the issues introduced by IE9.

I've tried simply opening the above mentioned jar, deleting the dojo/dijit folders and replacing them with the latest 1.6.1 version ones. This seems to have no effect, our select boxes remain useless in IE9 alone.

Anyone have any ideas?

I really don't want to go through the whole site and remove all dijit.form.select's just because MS decided to ignore a very popular framework!?

Comment: Dojo 1.6 does not support IE9 -- so you have to use the X-UA-Compatible header to force your web page into IE8 mode.  Without it, dijit's have enough browser-sniffing stuff (dojo.isIE calls) that prevents some widgets from working, especially drop-down list boxes.  However, Dojo 1.6.1 supports IE9 and you code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I did say above that I'd tried Dojo 1.6.1 to no effect. Anyway I found the answer, see below.

Comment: this will be strange, as I am quite sure Dojo 1.6.1 select boxes work in IE9.  You do NOT need the X-UA-Compatible header for Dojo 1.6.1.  If you have problems, you need to dig in further -- are you sure you have updated ALL the Dojo 1.6.1 files?

Comment: I simply opened the org.springframework.js-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar, deleted the dojo and dijit folders and finally copied in the dojo and dijit folders from the latest release (1.6.1) from the Dojo website. This didn't appear to help. At any rate I reverted back to my original springframework.js jar and added that X-UA tag instead. I'm happy with this "solution" (more like a workaround I know) but it will do in the meantime until we undergo a complete frontend redesign anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I can use the following tag in the head section of my universally included baselayout.jsp to force IE9 to act like IE8 without the user's knowledge and everything works fine again! Apparently the tag MUST be the first one in the head section.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```